# How should we handle Legends-specific Star Wars Q&As post-Disney-canon-revamp?

Tags: canon, discussion

How should we handle the questions which are specific to Legends (formerly C-canon EU) works, in light of [post-Disney new Canon rules](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76392/976)?

***Example***: " [What caused the damage to Nirauan described in "Hand of Thrawn" duology by Zahn?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7662/what-caused-the-damage-to-nirauan-described-in-hand-of-thrawn-duology-by-zahn) "

Comment: Ignore anything Disney-Star-Wars. Like the Matrix, the sequels just never happened.

Comment: @Kevin - I deeply truly wish I could. Hell, I even considered posting that as a separate answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Mark all such questions with a new [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) tag.

No need to edit anything in the answers

**Optionally**, some of the questions where EU works don't have an answer as of 2014, add an answer which states that most likely, this can never be answered since Lucasfilm indicated no new Legends (formerly EU C-canon) works will be published.

**Benefits:**

- Allows people who don't care about Legends/EU materials to easily filter out Legends specific content
- VERY self explanatory and intuitive, both for old-time EU fans (who tend to know what Legends mean) and to new fans brought in by 2015 release of Episode VII, who won't even know what EU means but might know the new Legends brand.

**Cons:**

- Requires a lot of work to retag all Legends specific questions
- May cause a flood of updates to Recently Updated questions page/feed.
- Both of these can be addressed if we collect a list of question IDs to retag; and request SE team to retag them on the back-end (should be 10 mins of work to BCP in a list of IDs, and run 1 update query on tags table).

---

- Just to elaborate on why a new tag is needed, instead of re-using existing [extended-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-universe) tag:

  1. That tag [**is not Star Wars specific**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-universe+-star-wars)
  2. It does it help new post-2014 fans who will view the site material without knowing what Extended Universe is in terms of Star Wars.
  3. Its Wiki is NOT relevant to Disney Star Wars Legends brand. And due to #1 it can't really be fixed.
  4. It can't be used to ignore "Legends-only" material due to #1.
  5. That tag isn't necessarily used consistently right now; and very possibly is present on questions which are NOT Legends-material-only even within Star Wars questions
  6. Vice versa, it is now missing from many existing Legends-only questions, meaning we would STILL need to do extensive cleanup to make the tag work - thus we don't even get the benefit of "well, EU tag already is on a bunch of questions, so it's less work".

Answer (score 1):

- Add a special note (akin to moderator notes on Skeptics.SE) explaining that the question deals with Star Wars Legends brand material.
- The rest of the answer same as [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5295/976), except that the note makes the [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) tag either optional or not needed at all.

Comment: Side note: I like the tag solution better, but this could be an alternative. One of its downsides is that I'm not sure if non-moderators can add such notes - if they cannot, this solution is bad due to extra load on moderators and lack of scalability across community.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to make any tagging distinction, and definitely not a moderator note. If a user wants answers from only one set of canon, they can indicate so in the question.

Comment: Just as a note: the meta question was also (or more) about existing questions, not only new ones. Also, -1 because I disagree that tagging distinction is not needed, sorry.

Comment: Applies to old ones too. There's no reason to go out of our way to do anything.

Comment: there are definitely reasons. Whether those reasons warrant the work is a different story.

Answer (score -3):

Just use the existing [extended-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-universe).

Comment: -1. That tag [**is not Star Wars specific**](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-universe+-star-wars), nor does it help new post 2014 fans who will view the site material without knowing what Extended Universe is in terms of Star Wars.

Comment: @DVK - Yes. This. Unless EU questions are segregated, the mass of irrelevant non-canon answers to canon questions will be huge.

Comment: @Richard - well, too bad. The mods said their word, nobody's gonna vote against what mods said

Comment: @DVK What a surreal comment. This very post has -2 at the moment.

Comment: @Keen - that may be because it was overly brief, AND had a legitimate objection to it as per my comment. The point is that mine were in the negative right after you chimed in that you don't like my proposal - and that is far from an unusual scenario (people tend to dislike a post a lot worse after a moderator disagrees with it).