# Should we replace the star-wars-eu tag with a star-wars-legends tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

In April 2014 [Disney re-branded the Star Wars Expanded Universe as "Legends"](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page). In light of this, should we replace [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu) with [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends)? This has been mentioned before (e.g. [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5295/31936)) in the context of *adding* [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) but not in the context of *replacing* the existing [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu).

There are currently [11 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu) tagged with [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu), and in general the tag was used appropriately for those questions. Quite a few more questions could use [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu)/[star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) but there is little need to add the tag to existing questions (especially before the release of Episode VII). But it seems to me that new questions may wish to specify canon vs. Legends, especially for events after Episode VI. This will become more likely after the release of Episode VII, but already there are some questions which are looking specifically for answers from Legends or contain only Legends material. For example:

- [Lightsaber claws in Expanded Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81891/31936)
- [Why was Skippy the Jedi Droid (R5-D4) force sensitive?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/79926/31936)

I propose creating [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) and setting [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu) as its synonym. Is this desirable? (And is it even possible to mark an existing tag as a synonym of another one?) This would use the correct brand name for non-canon Star Wars material (which is more likely to be used by younger users) without removing the Expanded Universe name that will more likely be recognized and used by older users.

If this is not possible, should we add [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) as a synonym with [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu) as its master tag?

Or should we just burninate [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu)?

Comment: I've started adding the new tag to some questions with highly upvoted answers so that the answers have a score >5 and can vote to approve star-wars-eu as a tag synonym.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I agree.**

- The tags should be linked together under the aegis of [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends).
- The [star-wars-eu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-eu) tag should continue to exist as a synonym.

Comment: So should I edit a question to add the star-wars-legends tag so that it gets created? Maybe the lightsaber claws one since it is only 2 days old? And then I can propose star-wars-eu as the synonym for star-wars-legends?

Comment: @Null - Both excellent suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure if adding as a synonym is a good idea. For example, while all pre-Disney starwars is legends, not all starwars material other than movies is legends. The current TV show is cannon, wouldn't it make it expanded universe, but not legends, since it IS canon? Regarding adding legends, totally agree with it

Comment: @Oak - There are now only three levels of canon; Canon,  Legends and non-canon. The new TV shows are Canon, meaning they share the same level of canonicity with the films

Comment: I understand that, but wouldn't it be better to split movies from Tv shows? Since, while they have the same level, one question may refer to one thing, and it could be spoiled by the movie/show

Comment: @Oak - I can see that being ok in theory but in practice it's a distinction without a difference. No one would use it that way.

Comment: @Richard I disagree, however I understand your point of view, and I agree with it, I just believe Tv-Theater should be distinguished. Eg: Veronica Mars film is the same level of canon as the TV shows, and a random question about it (on films/tv) would be a major spoiler. Hence why I have to disagree with you. However, you do make a very fine point.

Comment: Would it be worth retagging existing [star-wars-eu] questions as [star-wars-legends] and deleting [star-wars-eu] to avoid any future confusion?

Comment: @Boolean - How many are there?

Comment: @Valorum There are no questions last time i looked.