# Does this forum deal with the "non-canon" Star Wars Universe

Tags: scope, discussion, canon

Can I ask questions about the "non-canon" Star Wars Universe on this forum?

For Example: "How old was Jacen Solo when he died?"

That question has nothing to do with the movies and Disney has declared it "non-canon".

And how would I format such questions to be clear what I am asking?

Comment: Not only do we happily deal with it, but we also spend endless hours debating what constitutes canon and non-canon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes.

**Questions about Legends material from the Star Wars universe are on-topic.** (Hell, even questions about fan fiction are on-topic here, and material that used to be considered some level or other of canon is a lot higher up the pecking order than that!)

> *And how would I format such questions to be clear what I am asking?*

You can make clear in the text of your question that you're asking about Legends material as opposed to Disney canon, perhaps with a link or citation to the particular work you're referring to or asking about. We also have a [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) tag, whose [tag wiki info](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/star-wars-legends/info) says:

> Use this tag if your question references Legends sources and/or to indicate that answers are permitted to use Legends sources.

See also [How should we handle Star Wars Q&As post-Disney-canon-revamp?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5298/how-should-we-handle-star-wars-qas-post-disney-canon-revamp) and [How should we handle Legends-specific Star Wars Q&As post-Disney-canon-revamp?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5294/how-should-we-handle-legends-specific-star-wars-qas-post-disney-canon-revamp) here on meta.

Comment: You should probably state that fan-fiction is on-topic for questions, but not for answers to canon or Legends *Star  Wars* questions.

Comment: @RogueJedi Good point; edited.